# Need a responsive content slider

Tags: jquery, slider, responsive-design

Does anyone know of a responsive jQuery content slider?

I need a full width slider that features a single picture floated to the left or right taking up 50% of the slider area. Then It needs to have an additional text area taking up the other 50% of the slide.

I may be dreaming of the impossible, but it would be super cool if someone could point me in the right direction.

Perhaps the slide could look a little something like this.

[image: slider]

Comment: have you tried looking at google?  [jquery content slider](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1DVCJ_enUS426US426&sugexp=chrome,mod=16&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jquery+content+slider) the first result looks promising

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://www.swiperjs.com/ for a mobile based swipe solution, or make some adjustments to http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider

Comment: I'd also like to throw this one out there for consideration: https://github.com/mrbinky3000/responsive_carousel  It allows you to swipe with your fingers on touch devices and / or use navigation arrows.  Non-touch devices can even use the mouse to drag and / or use navigation arrows.

Answer (score 1):

[Liquid Slider](http://liquidslider.kevinbatdorf.com/) is one that I wrote which is fully responsive. the content can be any size and shape. If you have any questions, contact me.

Answer (score 0):

Unslider is pretty great... very small, powerful, flexible. http://unslider.com